# Calculating sum $\sum_{i>0} \sum_{j>0} \frac{i^2j}{3^i(j3^i+i3^j)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, contest-math, solution-verification

I am trying to calculate the (double) sum $\sum_{i>0} \sum_{j>0} \frac{i^2j}{3^i(j3^i+i3^j)}$, and I think i got it, but can someone verify it and see if any parts can be improved? (Simplified, justified, etc.)

My solution:

$$S=\sum_{i>0} \sum_{j>0} \frac{i^2j}{3^i(j3^i+i3^j)}$$

$$=\sum_{i>0}\sum_{j>0}\frac{i}{3^i}\cdot \frac{ij}{j3^i+i3^j}$$

$$=\sum_{i>0}\sum_{j>0}\frac{i}{3^i}\cdot\frac{\frac{i}{3^i}\frac{j}{3^j}}{\frac{j}{3^j}+\frac{i}{3^i}}$$

Now notice

$$S=\sum_{i>0}\sum_{j>0}\frac{i}{3^i}\cdot\frac{\frac{i}{3^i}\frac{j}{3^j}}{\frac{j}{3^j}+\frac{i}{3^i}}=\sum_{i>0}\sum_{j>0}\frac{j}{3^j}\cdot\frac{\frac{j}{3^j}\frac{i}{3^i}}{\frac{i}{3^i}+\frac{j}{3^j}}=S$$

$$\therefore S=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i>0}\sum_{j>0}(\frac{i}{3^i}+\frac{j}{3^j})\cdot\frac{\frac{i}{3^i}\frac{j}{3^j}}{\frac{j}{3^j}+\frac{i}{3^i}}$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{i\geq 1}\frac{i}{3^i}\right)\left(\sum_{j\geq 1}\frac{j}{3^j}\right)$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{2}{9}+\frac{3}{27}+\cdots\right)\left(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{2}{9}+\frac{3}{27}+\cdots\right)$$

Let $T=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{2}{9}+\frac{3}{27}+\cdots$

$$\frac{1}{3}T=\frac{1}{9}+\frac{2}{27}+\frac{3}{81}+\cdots$$

$$\frac{2}{3}T=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{27}+\cdots = \frac{\frac{1}{3}}{1-\frac{1}{3}}=\frac{1}{2}$$

$$T=\frac{3}{4}$$

$$\therefore S=\frac{1}{2}T^2=\frac{9}{32}$$

Thank you for helping.

Comment: This is Problem A-4 of the 1999 Putnam Competition.  The solution can be found here: https://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/.  I have not taken a look at your attempt, but the final answer is correct.

Comment: It looks correct to me. For simplifications, I would look at $$\sum_{i\ge 1} \dfrac{i}{3^i}$$ as that looks like way more justification than is needed. This summation is of the form $$\sum_{i \ge 1} i \cdot x^i = x\sum_{i\ge 1} i\cdot x^{i-1} = x\cdot \dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\sum_{i\ge 0} x^i\right) = x\cdot \dfrac{d}{dx} \dfrac{1}{1-x} = \dfrac{x}{(1-x)^2}$$

Comment: Now that I took a look at your solution, yes, you did it correctly.  It is about the same as Kiran Kedlaya's solution.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe oh wow I didn't see that. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Batominovski thank you for the link, i didn't know it was from a competition. Thank you for looking at my solution and helping.